# How to get past the locked gate

Tags: pc, hp-prisoner-of-azkaban

At the beginning of Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban (PC), when I have to go with Neville outside, before the main entrance, there is a locked gate. So we stay in the castle with Neville.

How do I get past this locked gate?